# Checking value to set `visible` in SAPUI5

Tags: xml, sapui5

I have to check if the value is null and if it is then I don't have to display label with value. I tried this way:

```
<f:fields
        visible="{= typeof(${Data>/online/value}) !== 'undefined' 
        &amp;&amp; ${Data>/online/value} !== null }">
  <Text visible="{= ${Data>/name} === 'firstScreen' }" text="{i18n>label}"/>
  <Text visible="{= ${Data>/name} === 'firstScreen' }" text="{=${Data>/online/value}}"/>
</f:fields>
```

but even if `Data>/online/value` is null it is displayed. Is there a syntax in `visible=` or?

Comment: something that's caught me out once or twice is trying to use the `visible` property on an element that doesn't actually have it. what is `f:fields`? you can always add it to the other visible checks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment a little, and without knowing what `f:fields` is exactly, I'm assuming it's one of the aggregations on a control the `sap.f` namespace, given that it starts with a lower case and an XML namespace of `f`.

Aggregations are like buckets that hold other elements, and they're part of an actual control. They do not have properties. This can be a little confusing because controls themselves, which can also have other elements, do have properties. This might be a reason the fields are always displayed in the example

It's probably better to move the visible check onto the Text field itself. You can probably shorten the check by coercing the value into a boolean:

```
!!${Data>/online/value}
```

When `undefined`, `null` or `""`, it'll evaluate to `false`, if it's a proper string or number, it'll evaluate to `true`.

The fields aggregation then looks more like:

```
<f:fields>
   <Label visible="{= ${Data>/name} === 'firstScreen' &amp;&amp; !!${Data>/online/value} }" text="{i18n>label}"/>
   <Text  visible="{= ${Data>/name} === 'firstScreen' &amp;&amp; !!${Data>/online/value} }" text="{=${Data>/online/value}}"/>
</f:fields>
```